# Problems adding images into java

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I'm currently trying to add an image as the background of a jFrame. I have successfully added one to a button, but for some reason I can't get it to add to the background of the frame. I know it's probably something really small that I just can't see lol

Code--

```
ButtonExample(){    
    JFrame f=new JFrame("Button Example");            
    JButton b=new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:\\MoreButton.png"));    
    b.setBounds(100,100,100, 40);  
    b.setSize(400,100);

    f.add(b);    
    f.setSize(600,800); 
    f.setContentPane(new ImagePanel("D://ahhahah.png"));

    f.setLayout(null);    
    f.setVisible(true);    
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
 }
```

Comment: Why is your ContentPane using linux style file separator? Probably that's the issue here.

Comment: Try to set the size of the `ImagePanel` with `.setSize(x,y);`

Comment: What is an "ImagePanel"? Also, when you 'add' something to your jframe, it gets added to the content pane. If you then 'setContentPane' the previous one is replaced.

Comment: @AvinashSagar The Windows APIs used by Java for files supports both the backslash and forwardslash as a path separator, so both should work, although the double `//` is technically wrong (but should work IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to know:

1. In your code you reference two files: `D:\MoreButton.png`
   and `D:\ahhahah.png`. On a modern version of Windows (I
   think since Windows NT 4.0) you can use `/` instead of
   `\`. So, alternatively just use:
   `D:/MoreButton.png` and `D:/ahhahah.png`.
2. In Java inside a string literal use `\\`, otherwise a
   single backslash is an escape for another sequence of characters.

As a consequence just use `String file="D:\\ahhahah.png"` or `String file="D:/ahhahah.png"`. I would prefer the second one.

Comment: I fixed it thank you, it was the way I referenced the files but also the names were jumbled up. :)